# Unknown column 'token' in 'field list' Code Igniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

So I'm making a function to blacklist an used token when user logout and save it to my database table, When I trying to insert the data to the table it always says `Unknown column 'token' in 'field list'` although the column is exists in the table. The error is basically telling me there is no `token` column in my table, and I already check if the value is passed correctly with `vardump` and it passed correctly to the function.

[image: dd($dataToken)]

`Table structure :`
[image: table structures]
How do I fix it ?

`Logout Function in Controller:`

```
 public function logout()
    {
        $model = new UserModel();
        $currentCookie = $_COOKIE['COOKIE-SESSION'];
        $dataToken = [
            'token' => $currentCookie,
            'logout_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")

        ];
        $model->addBlacklist($dataToken);
        setcookie('COOKIE-SESSION', null);
        return redirect()->to('/login');
    }
```

`Insert Model in UserModel :`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;
use CodeIgniter\Exceptions;
use CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use CodeIgniter\Controller\HomeController;
use Exception;
use CodeIgniter\View\View;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    use ResponseTrait;
    protected $table      = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'token', 'logout_at'];

    public function addBlacklist($dataToken)
    {
        $model = new UserModel();
        $builder = $this->table('jwtblacklist');
        //dd($dataToken);
        $model->save($dataToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !

turns out you can't insert data to different table in the same `model`,
because the `userModel` model is used for inserting data to `users` table.

So I created another model that used to insert blacklisted token to `jwtblacklist` table

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to insert data in a table different from the one defined/attached to the current Model. I.e:

```php
// ...

    public function addBlacklist($dataToken)
    {
        $this->db
            ->table('jwtblacklist')
            ->insert($dataToken);
    }

// ...
```

[Inserting Data](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#builder-insert)

`$builder->insert(?array $set = null, ?bool $escape = null);`